Opencv cuda pyton пытаюсь собрать с использованием cmake
Сборка практически получилась, но cmake выдаёт три ошибки:
CMake Warning at C:/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules/cudacodec/CMakeLists.txt:26 (message):
cudacodec::VideoReader requires Nvidia Video Codec SDK.  Please resolve
dependency or disable WITH_NVCUVID=OFF
Call Stack (most recent call first):
modules/world/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)
modules/world/CMakeLists.txt:50 (include_one_module)
CMake Warning at C:/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules/cudacodec/CMakeLists.txt:30 (message):
cudacodec::VideoWriter requires Nvidia Video Codec SDK.  Please resolve
dependency or disable WITH_NVCUVENC=OFF
Call Stack (most recent call first):
modules/world/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)
modules/world/CMakeLists.txt:50 (include_one_module)
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:1144 (include)
насколько я понимаю эти три модуля не подключились как это исправить?

Получилось решить? У меня такая же проблема. Пока работающего решения не нашел.
